# VB6 won't remember the Project References after shut down

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

VB6 is having trouble remembering the project references after exiting the project. For example i open a project, run the program, it won't run because of a compile error (Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic). So I go to Project > References (keep in mind that none of the references are marked as "Missing" also their reference path to the resource is correct), deselect three of the references that are .exe then hit OK. Next I would go back into the References again and re add those same exact three references. Then when I run it this time, the program is able to run just fine. (Also once I have re added the references I can re run the program in VB6 any as long as I don't exit out of VB6.) Now I save the project, exit VB6, open the same file I just closed and try to run it, it gives me the same exact compile error. I would have to re add those references to be able to run again.

What I'm trying to avoid is having to re add those references every time I have to go back into that project.

Comment: Check the .vbp file before and after correcting the issue.  The references are stored there.  Something is likely changing when the project is saved before you run it and doesn't get read back in by the IDE until you re-open the project.

Comment: I've already open the file in a text editor and their is no change. I've also tried changing the project reference path in the text editor to absolute path. That does however work for that instance until I shut vb6 down again, then I would have to relink those references again. Also when I relink the references, the paths to the reference becomes relative rather than staying absolute.

Comment: Something about how those references is registered on your dev PC is incorrect. This confuses the IDE in some fashion. I'd recommend unregistering / re-registering them.

Answer (score 0):

Something about how those references is registered on your dev PC is incorrect. This confuses the IDE in some fashion. I'd recommend unregistering / re-registering them.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution: I opened the .vbp file using Notepad ++ and corrected the invalid references with the correct path and it now remembers the project references for Word and Excel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).